# Работал-таки полжизни в профсоюзе/Профсоюзе

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Мой прадедушка, имевший имя Геннадий, работал-таки полжизни в профсоюзе/Профсоюзе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно с маленькой:

***Мой прадедушка, имевший имя Геннадий, работал-таки полжизни в профсоюзе***.

См. «Грамота.ру»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Там всë с маленькой.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

(1) *Мой прадедушка, имевший имя Геннадий, работал-таки полжизни **в профсоюзе.***

**Нарицательное** существительное, работник профсоюза на предприятии.

(2) *Мой прадедушка, имевший имя Геннадий, работал-таки полжизни **в Профсоюзе**.*

**Имя собственное,** например [Профессиональный союз работников народного образования и науки Российской Федерации](https://www.eseur.ru/).

Comment: В чём разница-то?

Comment: Я думаю, что профсоюзная организация  небольшого предприятия вряд ли является именем собственным. Кроме того, можно работать в центральной организации, имеющей собственное название, но писать строчную букву. Обычная практика для имен собственных, упрощенное и основное название.  Поэтому контекст нужен.